# ansible ec2_instance_facts filter by "tag:Name" does not filter by instance Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to run ec2_instance_facts to find an instance by name.  However, I must be doing something wrong because I cannot get the filter to actually work.  The following returns everything in my set AWS_REGION:

```
- ec2_instance_facts:
  filters:
    "tag:Name": "{{myname}}"
  register: ec2_metadata

- debug: msg="{{ ec2_metadata.instances }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use the [ec2_remote_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_remote_facts_module.html) module, not the ec2_instance_facts module.

```
- ec2_remote_facts:
    filters:
      "tag:Name": "{{myname}}"
  register: ec2_metadata

- debug: msg="{{ ec2_metadata.instances }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation [ec2_remote_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_remote_facts_module.html) is marked as DEPRECATED from ansible version 2.8 in favor of using [ec2_instance_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_instance_facts_module.html#ec2-instance-facts-module).

This is working good for me:

```
- name: Get instances list
  ec2_instance_facts:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    filters:
      "tag:Name": "{{ myname }}"
  register: ec2_list

- debug: msg="{{ ec2_metadata.instances }}"
```

Maybe the filte is not being applied? Can you go through the results in the object?